# Why there is no varchar datatype in DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReports to generate a report in PDF,XLS,DOC. But my database columns are in "varchar" datatype. So when I am using those fields in generating DynamicReports there is every other datatype other than varchar. I need varchar datatype because my column consists of commas, fullstops, numbers like these. So is there any option to convert or to get the datatype as varchar.

Here is my code:

```
public class DynamicReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
        StyleBuilder plainStyle = stl.style().setFontName("FreeUniversal");

        StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).bold().setBorder(stl.pen1Point());

        report
          .columns(
              Columns.column("Contact Person", "Contact_Person", DataTypes.stringType()))
          .title(//title of the report
                  Templates.createTitleComponent("Fonts"),
              Components.text("FreeUniversal").setStyle(boldStyle)
              .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
              .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
              .setDataSource("SELECT Contact_Person FROM marketing_database.lead", 
                                      connection);

        try {
            report.show();
            report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("c:/report.pdf"));
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Any help in this will be appreciated

Comment: What is a equivalent of varchar type in *Java*? String? Your question is unclear. What is a problem?

Comment: You have String for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dynamic Reports is based on Java, you can use the `String` data type for `VARCHAR` db types, as @AlexK and @KarthikeyanVaithilingam suggested.

> `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `LONGVARCHAR` could have been mapped to either `String` or `char[]`, but `String` is more appropriate for normal use. Also, the `String` class makes conversions between `String` and `char[]` easy: There is a method for converting a `String` object to a `char[]` and also a constructor for turning a `char[]` into a `String` object.

[Source](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.1-beta2-docs/guide/jdbc/mapping.doc.html)